# Do I need transit visa for my Bangkok layovers?

Tags: indian-citizens, india, layovers, transit-visas, thailand

I am an Indian citizen, travelling on Air Aisa from Mumbai via Bangkok to Manila. On the way there, the layover is 4 hours and is 5 hours on the return which is 15 days later. Do I need a transit visa for Thailand? If so, does it need to be multiple entry for the layover on the return journey?
sune

Comment: Because you included the 'india' tag, I added that you are an Indian citizen, which will make it easier to answer. If I am incorrect, I apologize, and you can undo my change.

Answer (score 1):

I assume your trip is on one ticket, Mumbai to Manila return. 
So you won't exit the transit area at Suvarnabhumi Airport.
You don't "enter" Thailand, just change airplane.

No need for any visa on either way.
Happy travelling